# A question on existence of a Sobolev Hilbert space, where convergence implies uniform convergence

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Is there a Sobolev Hilbert space $H^k(\Omega)$($\Omega$ open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$, with a smooth boundary), for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, such that, any sequence in the space $C^0(\bar{\Omega})\cap H^k(\Omega)$, that converges in the norm $\|.\|_{H^k}$, also has to converge in the norm $\|.\|_{C^0(\bar{\Omega})}$

Comment: Certainly when $k > m/2$ per [Sobolev embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#k_>_n/p).

Comment: Thanks @Hannes . I hadn't looked at the generalized versions of Sobolev inequalities in that page.

Comment: @Hannes : https://mathoverflow.net/q/308359/14414

Answer (score 1):

I guess that [Theorem 2.72](https://books.google.com/books?id=dUes-o_Y-BUC&pg=PA94) in  *Demengel,  F.  and  Demengel,  G.  (2012).Functional Spaces for the Theory of Elliptic Partial Differential Equations.* answers your question.